# Reducing Music Quality (320 kbps to 64 kbps)

Tags: java, php, android

I have a social media like android app which is bound to mysql php server and my server is not so big, **so i want to convert media to 64 kbps mp3 format without any exception**.

I have searched that how can i achieve this whether from android java or php but i couldnt find any answer.

Could you guys help me on giving any idea to how to do that or if there are any library for this where can i find it?

Thanks.

```
<?php

?php>
```

Comment: I like your code example... very informative.

Comment: It didnt let me to post question without code. I dont know what to do so how can i post any code?

Comment: Almost all questions you might have, about asking questions, are answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I know the rules sir, but this is the best of my try and i need help.

Comment: You're talking about downsampling or decimation. There are lots of libraries and apps available for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ffmpeg` library for Android.

Example 64k converting command : `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 64k output.mp3`

more information
[here](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a try (teşekkürler) :)

Comment: you are welcome :)